# List results by scope where (field) not nil THEN second condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, named-scopes

I'm wondering if there's a way to make one query to get the following conditions:

1) `scope :scheduled_for, -> {where.not(:scheduled_for => nil)}`

then

2) `scope :sort_by_position, -> {order('position')}`

The expected result would be the following list:

- Post 1 (Sept 23 && Position 1)
- Post 2 (Sept 24 && Position 2)
- Post 3 (Position: 3)
- Post 4 (Position: 4)
- etc...

Note: the position field could be random (i.e. Post 1 could have a position of 5 but since its scheduled_for is not empty, it takes precedence over a lower position post.

Comment: What's wrong with `Model.scheduled_for.sort_by_position` ?  That will only do the query when results are accessed, so it'll only be one query.

Comment: This only gives part of the result, i.e. a list of posts with scheduled_for and position NOT NIL. 

It doesn't give the second part of the list (where scheduled_for NIL and position NOT NIL)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple conditions in the `order_by`

```
order_by('scheduled_for IS NULL, position')
```

`scheduled_for IS NULL` returns "1" if true, "0" is false, so NULL values are greater (i.e. show up at the end of the list)